# Cannot add padding to JPanel (GridBagLayout), with 2 other JPanels inside

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

are you able to help me understand why there is no padding in `dataInputPanel` (the red border one)?

Goal: To have 10 padding on top, right, bottom, left in `dataInputPanel`

Error: No errors. It's just not working.

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame win = new JFrame();
        win.setTitle("Lord of the Rings - Battle Simulator");
        win.setSize(500, 600);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        win.setResizable(false);
        //-------------

        JPanel dataInputPanel = new JPanel();
        dataInputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 0));
        //dataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        dataInputPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 4, true));

        JPanel battleOutupPanel = new JPanel();
        //battleOutupPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        battleOutupPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 4, true));
        //-------------------------------------

        int paddingSize = 50;
        Insets paddingInsets = new Insets(paddingSize, paddingSize, paddingSize, paddingSize);

        // Heroes Data Input Panel - dataInputPanel GridBagLayout 1 row, 2 columns
        JPanel heroesDataInputPanel = new JPanel();
        //heroesDataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        heroesDataInputPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 4, true));

        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        gbc1.insets = paddingInsets;
        dataInputPanel.add(heroesDataInputPanel, gbc1);

        // Beasts Data Input Panel - dataInputPanel - GridBagLayout 1 row, 2 columns
        JPanel beastsDataInputPanel = new JPanel();
        //beastsDataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        beastsDataInputPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 4, true));

        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridy = 0;
        gbc2.insets = paddingInsets;
        dataInputPanel.add(beastsDataInputPanel, gbc2);
        //-------------

        win.add(dataInputPanel);
        win.add(battleOutupPanel);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Win:

```
public class Win extends JFrame {
}
```

Pnl:

```
public class Pnl extends JPanel {
}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to use `GridBagConstraints` and `Insets`, you must use `GridBagLayout` (here/instead of  `dataInputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 0));`)  (and don't forget to set weights and fill) -- `GridLayout` does not *care* about constraints

Comment: Don't call your classes "Window" and "Panel". There are AWT components with that name so it gets confusing. Class names should be more descriptive. Also 1) All Swing components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. 2) components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is visible.

Comment: Use a `EmptyBorder` (on `dataInputPanel`)

Comment: @camickr Thank you for the feedback. I changed the names. I will also read the article that you posted, however, I made sure to make that "win", was "setVisible" at the end, but the issue still persists.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for the feedback. I mean your solution does work, it's just a shame that the "win" need to be invisible. If you manage to find a way while making it still visible, please let me know, but thanks anyway.

Comment: *"it's just a shame that the "win" need to be invisible"* - I'm sorry, I don't understand - although, to be frank, extending from `JFrame` is generally considered a bad idea, you're not actually adding any new functionality to the class and it's just adding more confusion to the issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Well first off, yeah, I tried your suggestion, I created an ```EmptyBorder``` object ```EmptyBorder border1 = new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10);```, and I set it up on ```dataInputPanel```, and it did add the padding, but it also made it invisible. I would like the same result but to be able to see the border still. Second, I deleted the ```Win```, and ```Pnl``` classes in hopes to remove confusion. Thank you.

Comment: You really need to have a look at [How to use borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) - and focus in `CompoundBorder`

Comment: *I changed the names* - Those names are not any better. A class name should be descriptive. *but the issue still persists* - You didn't implement the suggestions in the first comment. Read the tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to understand how to use the constraints suggested in the comment. You don't need to use a Border, that is only one option. Then decide which approach you like. It will give you options in the future.

Comment: being more direct: **(i)** change `dataInputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 0));` to `dataInputPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`; **(ii)** add `gbc1.weightx = 1; gbc1.weighty = 1; gbc1.fill = BOTH;`; **(iii)** similar with `gbc2` (and, eventually, **(iv)** change `int paddingSize = 50;` to `int paddingSize = 10;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to have a look at [How to use borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) - and focus in `CompoundBorder`

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            JPanel dataInputPanel = new JPanel();
            dataInputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 0));
            dataInputPanel.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                    new LineBorder(Color.RED, 4, true), 
                    new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)
            ));
            //dataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
//            dataInputPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 4, true));

            JPanel battleOutupPanel = new JPanel();
            //battleOutupPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            battleOutupPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 4, true));
            //-------------------------------------

            int paddingSize = 50;
            Insets paddingInsets = new Insets(paddingSize, paddingSize, paddingSize, paddingSize);

            // Heroes Data Input Panel - dataInputPanel GridBagLayout 1 row, 2 columns
            JPanel heroesDataInputPanel = new JPanel();
            //heroesDataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            heroesDataInputPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 4, true));

            dataInputPanel.add(heroesDataInputPanel);

            // Beasts Data Input Panel - dataInputPanel - GridBagLayout 1 row, 2 columns
            JPanel beastsDataInputPanel = new JPanel();
            //beastsDataInputPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            beastsDataInputPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 4, true));

            dataInputPanel.add(beastsDataInputPanel);
            //-------------

            add(dataInputPanel);
            add(battleOutupPanel);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 600);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be it, thank you so much.
I will read the article provided.